# Extra decimal positions in excel values

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I'm trying to load some data into our application via excel upload and it appears like some number strings are not converting as in the Excel, but adjusting to a ‘close’ value with extra decimal positions.

Example:
0.65 in the excel becomes 0.6499999999999999 and 0.83 becomes 0.8299999999999999 in the database.

We have checked the display format on the cells in our spreadsheet to see if that displays it rounded to two positions or perhaps more positions or a formula in the actual cell data, but didn't spot anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

We are using Excel 2016.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is likely binary / decimal conversion errors. Some numbers are very simple to represent in decimal, but not so simple in binary. When those binary representations get rounded, the result is an inexact answer that can get converted back to decimal strangely. I suggest just rounding the values after they get into Excel.

```
=ROUND(A1,2)
```

should do the trick. If need be, you could use copy/paste values to overwrite the raw data. The function name is the same in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

That's life I'm afraid. Excel uses an IEEE754 double precision floating point type for numeric data, and that gives you, in the worst case, 15 decimal significant figures of precision.

`0.65`, for example, is **not** a dyadic rational, so cannot be represented exactly in floating point.

If you are not doing any numerical calculations on the data then your best bet is to treat the fields as text, by prefixing them with a single quotation character.